# time/clock always on?

Tags: 2.1-eclair, screen, clock

I need to have the time/**clock on** for about 30 mins. Just the time I can see in dark. The screen doesn't turn off.

Is there any application or way I can have the time on for xx minutes in case I need it?

**HTC Desire on Android 2.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Keepscreen](http://www.appbrain.com/app/keepscreen-%28now-free%29/com.tni.KeepScreenLite) can let you choose some applications and select a specific screen timeout for each of them. So you could just set the Clock application with the "no timeout" option.

Comment: cool, let me try ....

Answer (score 1):

There's a ClockView App. in google play store.
It's a best-efforted always on clock.
Please read the App. descriptions.
Link : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kimscom.clockview

Comment: What's your relationship with this app? Are you the publisher, or just a happy customer? (Either answer is fine, as long as you're honest about it.)